# Implementing google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm a nubee to android programming and am trying to implement google analytics into my first app. It's essential a focused phone book. I have the code, and have tried to put it in several different places, tried following the examples too. Keep getting error flags. What I am attempting to do is get the information to report on each number that is dialed. One activity, multiple instances:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CompanyListActivity extends Activity {

    private Button BRC;
    private Button Gotcha;
    private Button cab441;
    private Button CGT;
    private Button feedback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_company_list);


        BRC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BRC);
        BRC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } 
            });

       Gotcha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Gotcha);
       Gotcha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
                startActivity(callIntent);

        }
       });
```

How would I input the code for Google analytics?